# Webscraping in R: loop/automated how to?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to web scrape the page [www.numbeo.com](http://www.numbeo.com), which offers price comparisons for any city.
My focus is on the 80 largest cities of Germany, resident-wise.
Due to my recent restart to R, my skills are pretty outdated.

This is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
link = "https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Kaiserslautern"
page = read_html(link)
name = page %>% html_nodes(".priceValue") %>% html_text()
```

Question 1: I want to insert the 80 city names into the URL through a loop (instead of "Kaiserslautern" f.e.), through which I collect a specific price given on the webpage for each city. This collecting should be saved in a csv file in a dataframe. How does the code look?

Question 2: Currently I am accessing the node html_nodes(".priceValue"), which collects all prices shown in the page. I want only one price, namely for the monthly ticket cost of transportation.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `link_vector = paste0("https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/", city_vector)`, where `city_vector` is a vector of your cities. Then `pages = lapply(link, read_html)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow discourages "how does the code look" questions. Maybe my steps can help you code it yourself, if you get lost somewhere, you can just ask again.

Step 1. Get a all the city names and put them into a vector. Good practice: get the list of cities from wikipedia, they should be in a table that can be scraped very nicely. Get the first 80 entries of that list and put them into a variable. OR just copy and paste the list into RStudio and create the vector manually. [wiki link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Gro%C3%9F-_und_Mittelst%C3%A4dte_in_Deutschland)

Step 2. Use that vector to creates a data.table. Your vector is the first column of the data.table. Name that first column "city". Add a second, empty column to you data.table, that is called "transportation cost".

Step 3. Create a loop that does the following things:

- create the path to the website of the city
- connect to the website of the city
- scrape the value you are looking for from that cities city (either use CSS Selector gadget or the developer tools of your browser to find the right value)
- put the value into the data.table at the right position
- start the loop again with the next city

Step 4. You should endup with a data.table that contains 80 city names and the 80 values. Export the data.table as csv.

Thats not a lot of code and it can possibly be written with very few lines of code. Id recommend using more lines of codes till it work properly, then start optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a specific question for the following part. I created beforehand a list of cities to automatically add the city names at the end of the URL. Unfortunately, the website expects sometimes a "-Germany" at the end of some cities as well. Therefore, I wanted to write a sexy if/else - code for that. But what is wrong?

ds=list("Berlin", "Hamburg"...81 cities)

city_cost= data.frame()

for (city in ds){

num_link= paste0("https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/", city)

num_page= read_html(num_link)

if (is.null(num_page)){

```
num_link_new= paste0("https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/", city, "-Germany")

num_page_new= read_html(num_link_new)

num_table= num_page_new %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[2] %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]

city_cost = rbind(city_cost,data.frame(num_table[31,2]))
```

}

else {

```
num_table= num_page %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[2] %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]

city_cost = rbind(city_cost,data.frame(num_table[31,2]))
```

}

}